# Indirect left recursion in my grammar?

Tags: parsing, recursion, compiler-construction, grammar, left-recursion

My grammar appears to have a case of indirect left recursion, looked at some of the other similar question, cannot quite make a mental connection between them and my grammar, I can't get my head around how to solve it.

```
A  ::= A' a
     | A
     | b

A' ::= c
     | A
```

`A'` is called from `A` but `A'` is `c` or `A`, this is causing the left recursion, how could this be rearranged to an equivalent grammar while eliminating the left recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following productions:

```
1:  A  -> A' a
2:  A  -> A
3:  A  -> b
4:  A' -> c
5:  A' -> A
```

First note that production #2 makes this grammar ambiguous, and is actually kind of pointless. Let's remove it.

```
1:  A  -> A' a
3:  A  -> b
4:  A' -> c
5:  A' -> A
```

The "Left recursion" article on Wikipedia contains an (unsourced) [algorithm to eliminate all left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_all_left_recursion), including indirect left recursion. Let's ignore this specific algorithm and focus on the idea instead: first turn indirect recursion to direct recursion through substitution, then resolve direct recursion by adding a tail non-terminal.

For instance, we can substitute `A'` in production #1 by replacing it with

```
6:  A  -> c a    (see #1 and #4)
7:  A  -> A a    (see #1 and #5)
```

The grammar becomes as follows:

```
4:  A' -> c
5:  A' -> A
6:  A  -> c a
7:  A  -> A a
```

and we've already turned all indirect recursion into direct recursion. All that remains is to remove the direct recursion for `A`:

```
4:  A' -> c
5:  A' -> A
6:  A  -> c a T
8:  T  -> epsilon
9:  T  -> a T
```

Comment: (I was in a hurry, so if you notice any mistakes or odd things, please don't hesitate to ask.)